# How can I put limit and get only names of the games using RAWG api?

Tags: api, url

I am using RAWG api to get names of the Games based on genre currently I am just testing the url requests and I could come with this code
https://api.rawg.io/api/games?limit=1&genre%20=%20action
But the problem here is I am getting bunch of information as json file, I just want the name of 5 games.
Can anyone help me :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using flask to store the data from the URL request the problem now I face is I get the same results for different set of genre suppose if I pass  this https://api.rawg.io/api/games?limit=1&genre%20=%20racing the same set of results come

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is pretty clear on how to call it (see the [docs](https://api.rawg.io/docs/#operation/games_list)) and what it does return:

As you can see here, the calls always returns a json with `count` and `results`, where result is an `array` of `Game` which consists of more fields than the name.

However, you can limit the amount of games returned by using the `page_size` parameter, leaving you with: https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page_size=5&genre%20=%20action

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem I face now is i get same results of game irrespective of changing the genre suppose if I pass https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page_size=5&genre%20=%20racing the results stays the same

Comment: The parameter is called genres ... genres=racing

Comment: Thanks for the answer I even tried this but it returns same set of results https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page_size=5&genres%20=%20racing

Comment: you may remove the useless %20, &genres=racing ;)